# node_modules polluting my codebase

Tags: node.js, npm

Hello I'm new to Node and in particular the dependency management system. When installing a module I find that my codebase is being covered by lots of dependencies when the actual code I've written is not that lengthy. I've also noticed that sometimes when I do an npm install instead of packaging all of the dependencies under one folder representing the module I'm downloading sometimes the modules dependencies endup sitting in parallel polluting the main folder. For example, I created a module that had maybe 3 sub modules that all are used by the main module and fit well together.

```
index.js
node_modules
     my_authentication_module
     my_authorization_module
     my_persistance_module
```

Then when I installed an AWS dependency the number of modules jumped considerable so my code base looks like

```
index.js
node_modules
     my_authentication_module
     my_authorization_module
     my_persistance_module
     aws_module_1
     aws_module_2
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     aws_module_20
```

**Problem**

This is cluttering my code and making it look like theres a lot more going on than there is. Is there a more efficient way of managing a node project?

**Secondary Question**

How come running "npm install some-module --save" does not confine all of the modules dependencies to a single folder? Or is there a way of doing this so that if some package needs 50 packages I don't end up with 50 packages sitting in parallel with the package that needs them.

For example. Instead of:

```
node_modules
     my_authentication_module
     my_authorization_module
     my_persistance_module
     aws_module_1
     aws_module_2
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     aws_module_20
```

It would be nice to get

```
node_modules
     my_authentication_module
     my_authorization_module
     my_persistance_module
     aws
        node_modules
           aws_module_1
           aws_module_2
           .
           .
           .
           .
           .
           aws_module_20
```

So at least navigating to the top level you can easily see theres only really 3 modules of interest with a bunch of AWS dependencies crammed neatly into one folder. Is anything like this possible?

Comment: What you're asking for is how npm up through version 2.x behaved. The unnecessary nesting caused various issues, so they changed the algorithm in version 3.0.0. I do not believe the behavior is configurable.

Comment: I don't understand how things in `node_modules` "pollute your codebase", or "clutter" your code. They are just sitting there, harming no-one, and you basically never need to worry about them or even look at them. If you want to see the dependency structure, try `npm ls`. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9809).

Comment: @torazaburo If you say this is normal in the realm of node/npm then I don't mind. But its not true that don't have to worry about them or look at them. I can only imagine what my code would look like if I was using Maven or Gradle and every underlying JAR put its classes into my source code instead of tucked away in a lib directory.... Again if this is normal, in NPM usage, then I'll just adapt, but I'd like to be sure this isn't me misusing NPM or package.json improperly.

Comment: @mscdex I see. Should I myself avoid nesting my own dependencies then? For example I've been separating responsibilities into the node_modules folder of the parent module that uses them. If this causes problems for npm should I be keeping my own custom modules in parallel and not placing them in the node_modules folder?

Comment: But `node_modules` **IS** a lib directory where the classes are "tucked away". Why exactly do you think you need to worry about them? It has nothing to do with your source code. It's completely separate from it. Where would you prefer to keep them? In a directory called `.dont-look-at-this-directory`?

Comment: @torazaburo hmmm. Ok maybe I've been structuring the project wrong. When I create a custom module I've been placing it into the node_modules folder. Initially seemed like the thing to do. I've been treating it like "packages" in the JVM but sounds like I should keep them in a separate directory specific to my domain? Trying to make it obvious to the next developer what components I wrote and did not. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be misinterpreting the purpose of `node_modules`. It is exclusively the province of `npm` (or `yarn` etc.). It will never include your own code (except perhaps other separate packages of yours, which are brought in as dependencies). It is (usually) not version-controlled; that is, it is `.gitignored`'d. At any point, it should be able to erased entirely and repopulated with a simple `npm install`. Of course, as with anything, there are more nuances and divergent opinions here that are discussed in detail across the web.

There are many ways to manage and structure your own code and artifacts. In many cases, it will go under a `src` or possibly `lib` directory at the top of the project, parallel to `node_modules`. Within `src`, some people prefer to group code by function (eg, controllers, routers, services), while others prefer to group by area of concern--that's a matter for the project owner to decide.

In any case, since `node_modules` is fundamentally not your direct concern, it is of no real consequence whether `npm` organizes the dependencies in hierarchical fashion, as was the case with `npm@2`, or in flat fashion, as with `npm@3`. Yes, it can be a bit disconcerting to see a `node_modules` with 100 entries or 500, but that's really a matter for `npm` to worry about, and there are good reasons for the change made with `npm@3`.